# Any up to date Plutus tutorials for how to use the Emulator Trace?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-starter, development

I've recently updated my plutus-starter based app to the latest version, and it now references plutus-apps v0.1.0, and there are a lot of changes compared to what I started with in January.

It seems the data types and functions for using wallets and setting up the Emulator has changed a lot.

Does anyone have a link for a good tutorial on how to run the Emulator to test your contracts out?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the plutus-contract tests which use the Emulator Trace
https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-contract/test/Spec

Comment: ok, Thanks. I'm going to look at some files like plutus-apps/doc/plutus/tutorials/Auction.hs, to try to figure out how this testing/emulator set up all works.